# Browsing Pictures on a Mac

Tags: linux, macos, iphoto, aperture

After many years using linux, I decided to buy a mac. Now my main 
problem is: how do I synchronize pictures within my linux machines and the
mac?

I have been using digikam in linux, and I like it because I can just browse the pictures directly from my directories (and it is easy for me to keep directories synchronized within mac and linux).

I have been testing iphoto and aperture, which are quite nice but if use them, my understanding is that I have to import all the pictures into these softwares, and this 
doesn't seem to be the ideal solution for me.
I tried picasa, but I don't find it as good as iphoto and aperture. On the other hand it allows me to browse directories, without having two copies of the same pictures.

I didn't try lightroom yet, would that be a good solution?

I would appreciate any suggestion on this.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

Aperture can leave your files where they were.  HOWEVER  If you rename a file outside of aperture, aperture can't find it, and you lose your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this related thread](https://superuser.com/questions/194490/importing-photos-on-mac-os-x) is an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I didn't see the thread before, I don't think it gives me an answer, as the OP asks how to get this done in iPhoto. I am more flexible and I am happy to use any other software, if there is a better alternative!

Comment: @MrWoody: Yes, but the 2x upvoted answer there shows that iPhoto works as well without importing (i.e. moving/copying files into proprietary database), which is the only argument you bring against it. Other kinds of software recommendation can only be vague and subjective without your providing criteria.

Comment: The solution described there is nice but it doesn't show how to use iPhoto as a file browser, as I don't think it is possible. I understand that it is possible not to have two copies of the same file (i.e. leave pictures as they are) but since I have a lot of pictures, it wouldn't be convenient to "import" all of them.

Comment: @MrWoody: Doesn't iPhoto allow mirroring of physical folders using the groups inside the application? Also, if you use a folders synchronizer, you can use [Finder](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29853/SuperUser/finderphotos.png) to browse the folders, if that structure is important to you, and the other application, such as iPhoto, for tagging, Faces, retouching etc. Please clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: How do you mirror physical folders with iPhoto? My aim is to have a nice software which can browse directories on my mac, edit them and have slideshows. What is the screenshot from ?

Comment: You don't -- in iPhoto. As you wrote "it is easy for me to keep directories synchronized", so I assumed you already know how to sync folders (there are enough general purpose syncing solutions). Screenshot is Finder, icon view, large icons, icon preview enabled, and QuickLook. QuickLook also supports slideshows, just select multiple files. If your editing is rather light and/or rare, why not use your file manager and QuickLook for viewing/browsing, and edit using Pixelmator, or Acorn, or even Preview? It doesn't sound like you need the faces/places/albums/... stuff from iPhoto anyway

Comment: yes, I know how to sync folders (I use unison). I do some editing, so finder is not the right solution for me.

Comment: I don't think there is such a program. Either learn to live with both Finder/Image editor, or lose the physical folders (or recreate them as groups or what it's calles) in an application like iPhoto.

Comment: Don't Picasa and Lightroom satisfy my requests? I was just looking for advice on which one is the best application for this purpose

Comment: Haven't used Lightroom, don't like Picasa (which you dismissed anyway). However, I wonder why a solution so simple hasn't generated a useful answer by now. You could try clarifying the question text and especially title, because at least to me, it seems misleading. This doesn't seem to be about syncing, but about photo management software that keeps the underlying directory structure.

Comment: I edited title and a bit of my question. Let's see if I get any answer in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one true answer here that will work with everyone. It demands on whether you want a DAM+Editing software or a split between the two or just the latter.

I used Bibble back in the day (which is now named Corel AfterShot Pro) for Mac-Linux-Windows editing, with Picasa for DAM/overview, and then switched to Lightroom when Bibble 5 came out due to the confusing new DAM. Lightroom worked OK when sharing the same catalogue between Mac and Windows, but then I upgraded Lightroom 6 to Lightroom CC and suddenly I was forced into paying a monthly sum to access my old edits.

Corel AfterShot Pro still works cross-platform, so someone interested in cross-platform products could still use that (its 5x faster than Lightroom), but I haven't used it in many years. But I see you were using digiKam. That actually works on Mac, Windows and Linux, doesn't cost a dime and is still updated 18 years on. If you like(d) this, I'd just install it on your Mac as well. Super-simple syncing.

I am actually pondering whether to start using that instead of my slow old Lightroom install. If you see my experiences above, the one general thread is that vendor lock-in for DAM has been hurtful. Software dies, gets slow or not updated or turns into something else. Open Source software can still die (see F-Spot), but at least it's usually available for most platforms and it's possible to fix it.